# How to get an iterator over the return values of member function?

Tags: c++, oop, iterator

```
class A
{
   public:
     const B& GetB() const;
};

vector<A> manyA;

template<typename ConstBIter>
void foo(ConstBIter beginB, ConstBIter endB);
```

Whats the most elegant way to get a iterator over the Bs stored in A. Could get the pointers, store them in an array and use a boost::indirect_iterator. But there is certainly a better way?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html

Answer (score 0):

Write your own iterator class. In C++, you are not limited to using only the iterator classes that are defined in the standard C++ library.

If your class meets the requirements for an iterator, as defined in the C++ standard, it can be used with the C++ library anywhere where any other iterator, that meets the same requirements, can be used.

Many large software libraries, in fact, declare and define their own iterators, for their own particular purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution...

```
typedef boost::transform_iterator<boost::function<B&(A&)>, vector<A>::iterator> BIter;

BIter beginBIter(manyA.begin(), boost::mem_fn(&Layer::GetB));
BIter endBIter(manyA.end(), boost::mem_fn(&Layer::GetB));
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer to indicate that the problem in this question has been solved. That's a common practice on SO.